# Switch Statement with three cases in C. Third Case is not running properly

Tags: c, switch-statement, break, do-while

below is a do-while loop that I coded. When I run it, the first two cases do their job and run perfectly. However. the third case is supposed to quit the program but instead it does nothing and just goes back to the series of printf statements in the beginning of the do-while loop. Any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong?

```
do
{
    printf("Choose one of the following (1, 2, or 3) \n");
    printf("1. Find GCD of two positive integers\n");
    printf("2. Sort 3 integers in the ascending order\n");
    printf("3. Quit the program\n");
    printf("Please enter your choice: ");
    scanf("%d", &option);
    switch (option)
    {
        case 1:
            gcd(p, q);
            printf("\nDo you want to try again? Say Y(es) or N(o): ");
            getchar();
            response = getchar();
            break;

        case 2:
            sort(p, q, r);
            printf("\nDo you want to try again? Say Y(es) or N(o): ");
            getchar();
            response = getchar();
            break;  

        case 3:
            break;
    }
}
while (response == 'Y' || response == 'y'); //Condition that will determine whether or not the loop continues to run.
printf("\nThank you for using my progam. Goodbye!\n\n");
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Response variable remains either Y or y and while loop never exits.

add

```
response = 'x'; //or something that isn't Y or y
```

before break; in case 3: option.

Answer (score 2):

`break` statement exits from first iterative loop. In your case this is  `switch`.

You must modify the response ( for example response =0).

```
    case 3:
        response=0; //different than 'Y' or 'y'
        break;
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

```
case 3:
  return 0;
```

You also might consider eliminating case 3 and just do this:

```
default:
  return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You just interrupt the switch case.

How about using:

```
  case 3:
      return;
      break;
```

Comment: FWIW, this suggestion would work, but the `break` after the `return` is unnecessary (the code is unreachable, and the compiler will warn you.) It also appears this function returns an int, so you'll most likely want to `return 0` instead of just `return`.

Answer (score 0):

in case 3,there is no input coming from the user, so the response variable remains true, try asking the user for an input or just put response = '(any letter that will make the condition false)'

Answer (score 0):

`break` statement does not exit the program, it just exits from the `switch` block.
To exit :
   1.
    `#include<stdlib.h>`
     And instead of `break` statement, use `exit(0);`
   2.Change the `case 3` as follows:

`response='N';break;`

Answer (score 0):

The break statement in case 3 just exits from case 3 rather than from the program.
If you want to exit the program in case 3 then use the return statement.

return 0;

This statement exists the program rather than repeating the while loop.